# How to declare an array with const int items in a struct

Tags: c, struct, global-variables

I'm trying to create a struct with an array inside.  The  array size, I'm hoping, should be set at compile time.  That is it's hard coded but uses a variable so I can change it easily in the code.  Problem is I'm getting linker errors when I use const int in the header ahead of the struct definition.  Here's my code:

from the header file:

```
const int t_Module_qInternalParams =64;

typedef struct Module{
    double internalParams[t_Module_qInternalParams];
} t_Module;
```

Comment: why not use a `#define`?

Comment: Thanks @FelixPalmen still getting the hang of stack overflow

Comment: `That is it's hard coded but uses a variable so I can change it easily in the code. `...what is that?

Comment: @SouravGhosh. I mean use the same number in the code many times.  Changed when editing code, not at run time.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
const int t_Module_qInternalParams = 64;
```

Is a *constant* in the sense that the *object* cannot be modified after initialization, but it's still a variable. Especially, `t_Module_qInternalParams` is **not** a *compile-time constant*, as required in your declarator.

A simple solution is to use a preprocessor macro instead:

```
#define MODULE_INTERNALPARAMS 64
```

This just expands to `64` **before** the compiling phase starts, and of course, `64` **is** a *compile-time constant*.

Comment: THANK YOU.  I'm still just starting out!